# "bytearray.fromhex()" not returning the correct hex

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to convert a string to bytes. I have this function:

```
def unpack_byte_data(self, byte_arr):
    byte_str = byte_arr.decode('utf-8')
    print("BYTE_STR", byte_str)
    byte_data = bytearray.fromhex(byte_str)
    print("BYTE_DATA", byte_data)
    return byte_data
```

But, as we see below, I'm not getting the correct result. The `BYTE_STR` does not match the resulting `BYTE_DATA`.

```
BYTE_STR 080e36860001
BYTE_DATA bytearray(b'\x08\x0e6\x86\x00\x01')
```

Why am I getting the wrong number of bytes with bad data?

Comment: That's the right output. Bytes corresponding to printable ASCII (like `\x36`) are displayed as the corresponding ASCII characters (`6` here).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

This is supposed to convert to 0x08, 0x0e, 0x36, 0x86, 0x00, 0x01

Right?

Comment: You mean \x0e6 is actually \x0e \x36?

Comment: Look at `[hex(b) for b in byte_data]`. It evaluates to `['0x8', '0xe', '0x36', '0x86', '0x0', '0x1']`. If you find Python3 byte literals to be confusing, you are not alone.

Comment: You can use a list comp to print it as hex escapes, eg `print("".join([f"\\x{u:02x}" for u in byte_data]))`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments from  'user2357112 supports Monica'.

When you print a byte array, any byte that can be considered an ASCII character is printed as an ASCII character.

So, `\x0e6` is really `\x0e`, `\x36`, as `\x36` is the ASCII character `6`.

This would have been more obvious if were a non-hex letter, but bad luck.

John Coleman explained how to print a `bytearray` as one would expect using a list comprehension:

`[hex(b) for b in byte_data]`

I think this is a tricky behavior and it's worth keeping this answer here.